# Can I display a popup over a CFDOCUMENT page?

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, cfdocument

Here's what I'd like to do in Coldfusion:

On a webpage there is a "Download" href link and I want another browser tab to open when the user clicks this link. In the new tab, I am creating a PDF via CFDOCUMENT in Coldfusion. This in of itself works.

However, since the PDF has a delay before it loads in the tab, I want to display a popup to the user that the PDF may take a few moments to load.

So what I tried to do was this sequence:

```
User clicks "Download" -> 
On the same page, I trapped the link with jquery and displayed a popup 
window alerting the user there may be a delay ->
User clicks OK on the popup ->
Using javascript window.open, redirected to a new browser window for the PDF.
```

This was unsuccessful because using `window.open` in javascript is not trusted by browsers and the new tab doesn't show up because of popup blockers.

So then I thought I'd create a popup in the new browser tab instead before the PDF loads, but discovered I can't use javascript on a page with CFDOCUMENT.

Any ideas as to how to best accomplish this if anything can be done?

Comment: Instead of a pop-up, display html with cfflush.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? I tried running a test in a small pdf file:
      <div>test</div>

    <cfflush>

    <cfdocument format="pdf">
       This is a test pdf.
    </cfdocument>

'Test' appeared before the pdf did successfully, but when the PDF loaded, it wasn't a pdf anymore. Lots of encoded stuff....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [iframe](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) might be your friend here. It allows you to display another document in the pdf page.

Using your example in the comment, I created two files: one to display the prompt message and one to display the PDF.

---

**cfprompt.cfm**

```
<body>
<div> this is a test </div>
</body>
<cfflush> 
<iframe src="pdf.cfm" >
</iframe>
```

---

**pdf.cfm**

```
<cfdocument format="pdf">
    <h1>Hello ColdFusion</h1>
    <p>This is <strong>PDF</strong> example document.</p>
    <p>Genereated at: <cfoutput>#TimeFormat(Now())# on #DateFormat(Now())#</cfoutput></p>
</cfdocument>
```

---

You're still going to have to play with the formatting/sizing of the iframe so that it displays correctly, but hopefully this allows you to display the PDF.

Comment: Thanks! I tried that and it worked. The only thing that I'd need to add is the CFHEADER and CFCONTENT in the pdf.cfm file to treat the iframe as a pdf document so if the user tries to save, it will save it as a pdf.

Comment: No Problem, Glad to hear this helped! (If this post answered your question, you should accept it as the correct answer by clicking the checkmark by the votes for the answer)